# Textview Inside Fragment Showing Irrelevant Texts

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I am new at android app development. My problem is I am trying to show an arabic text at the a textview which is located inside a fragment.

**Details:**

**Here in my case; textview putting some irrelevant words - which are not included in the passed string(arabic text that must be shown). I discovered that it is about the font.Because irrelevant text changes according to font i used. Below there are links for two screenshots from my app. At the one of them you can see that "null" word is written at the most left of the first line. But if i change the font to arabic one the "null" word leaving its place to an arabic string.**

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgs1D.jpg)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17UF4.jpg)

**I want to get rid of this "null" word but icouldnt find how to do it. I would be glad if someone show.**

Arabic text is being specified according to a string variable of an object "comingVird" which is instance of "Vird.class" I built.

Here is my fragment class:

```
package com.codeforlite.virdlerim.Fragments;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.codeforlite.virdlerim.R;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Fragment_Arabic_Image extends Fragment{

    private String imageName;
    private  View view;
    private TextView txt_oku_arabic_Text;
    private String arabicText;
    private Image image;

    public Fragment_Arabic_Image(String imageName,String arabicText) {
        this.imageName = imageName;
        this.arabicText=arabicText;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_arabic_image,container,false);

        //define textview 
      
        txt_oku_arabic_Text=view.findViewById(R.id.txt_oku_arabic_Text);
        txt_oku_arabic_Text.setText(arabicText);
 
        

        return view;
    }
    
}
```

Here is my activity class: ( Inside the activity; there is a bottom navigation view with three fragments.One of the fragments "Fragment_Arabic_Image" is problem.)

```
package com.codeforlite.virdlerim;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.codeforlite.virdlerim.Fragments.Fragment_Anlam;
import com.codeforlite.virdlerim.Fragments.Fragment_Arabic_Image;
import com.codeforlite.virdlerim.Fragments.Fragment_Turkce_Okunus;
import com.codeforlite.virdlerim.Vird_Classes.AyetGrubu;
import com.codeforlite.virdlerim.Vird_Classes.Vird;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.io.Serializable;


/*this activity is to read a text with a counter- it shows arabic and turkish spelling and also meaning
in different fragments*/
public class Oku extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

    private int actualNumber;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private Fragment tempFragment;
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private FrameLayout fragmentContainer;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btn_tıkla;
    private Vird comingVird;
    private Fragment arabicImageFragment;
    private Fragment turkishTextFragment;
    private Fragment anlamFragment;
    private MediaPlayer clickSoundPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer completeSoundPlayer;
    private Vibrator vb;
    private SharedPreferences kalanSayiKayit;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor kalanSayiKayitEditor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_oku);

        //to save the number at the counter
        kalanSayiKayit=getSharedPreferences("kalansayilar",MODE_PRIVATE);
        kalanSayiKayitEditor=kalanSayiKayit.edit();

        //initialize views
        fragmentContainer=findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        bottomNavigationView=findViewById(R.id.bottom_navi);
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btn_tıkla=findViewById(R.id.button_tıkla);

        //sound at every button click
        clickSoundPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.click);

        //sound will be played when target reached
        completeSoundPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.complete);

        //vibrator for button click
        vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        //coming vird with the intent
        comingVird= (Vird) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Vird.class");

        actualNumber=comingVird.getTargetNumber();

        //put the arabic image fragment on the container first
        arabicImageFragment=new Fragment_Arabic_Image(comingVird.getImageName(),comingVird.getArabicText());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,arabicImageFragment).commit();

        //eğer gelen vird ayet ise Anlam Sekmesini Meal Sekmesi yap
        if(comingVird.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("AyetGrubu")){bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setTitle("Meal");}


        //on navigation item selected:
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                //get the selected items id number
                int itemID=item.getItemId();

                //if id number is related to the arabic image fragment, set the temp fragment as arabic image fragment
                if(itemID==R.id.action_oku_arapca){
                    tempFragment=new Fragment_Arabic_Image(comingVird.getImageName(),comingVird.getArabicText());
                }

                //if id number is related to turkish text fragment, set the related fragment
                else if(itemID==R.id.action_oku_turkce) { tempFragment=new Fragment_Turkce_Okunus(comingVird.getTurkishText());}

                //if id number is related to the meaning set meaning fragment..
                else if(itemID==R.id.action_oku_anlamı){

                    //to change the text on the bottom navigation bar item
                    if(comingVird.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("AyetGrubu")){
                        AyetGrubu ayetGrubu=(AyetGrubu)comingVird;
                        tempFragment=new Fragment_Anlam(ayetGrubu.getMeal());}
                    }

                    else{
                         tempFragment=new Fragment_Anlam(comingVird.getMeaning());
                    }


                //replace the fragment on the container with the temp fragment
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,tempFragment).commit();

                return true;

                }
            });

        //initiate progress bar with full progress
        progressBar.setProgress(100);

        //show the number of the counter on the button
        btn_tıkla.setText(""+actualNumber);

        //on button click
        btn_tıkla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(actualNumber<=1) {
                    progressBar.setProgress(0);
                    btn_tıkla.setText("Tebrikler\nhedefinize ulaştınız!");
                    btn_tıkla.setTextSize(15);
                    vb.vibrate(500);
                    completeSoundPlayer.start();

                }

                else{
                    actualNumber--;
                    kalanSayiKayitEditor.putInt(comingVird.getId(),actualNumber);
                    kalanSayiKayitEditor.commit();

                    progressBar.setProgress(100*actualNumber/comingVird.getTargetNumber());
                    //decrease the number and set on the text of the button

                    btn_tıkla.setText("" + actualNumber);

                    clickSoundPlayer.start();

                    //her button tıklamada kısa titreşim ver
                    vb.vibrate(100);
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is the xml of fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_arabic_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_oku_arabic_Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quran"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textSize="30sp"
               
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: have you verified that `comingVird.getArabicText()` gives you proper text? (in `onCreate` of `Activity`)

Comment: Yes, i can see that there is no problem at the content of the string while debug.

Comment: check if it is still valid when set to `TextView`. can you post `R.layout.fragment_arabic_image` XML file? what does you mean by "But they belong to another class."? this additional text is another `R.string` or separated `View` with hardcoded text or maybe some dynamic value passed somewhere in `Bundle`? I don't see nothing suspicious in your code...

Comment: I updated and  clarified my question.You can see above. Thanks for your interest by the way

Comment: are you shure that proper `String` (without unwanted prefix with names) is passed into `Fragment_Arabic_Image(String imageName,String arabicText)` constructor? put some log in there to find out, it also tell you how many times it gets called (should once). also show `Virt` and `Esma` classes, maybe you have some `static` fields there?

Comment: I figured out that it is about the font.When i changed font irrelevant words become "null" text.But i still couldnt find how to make disappear it